# regex for url parameter value in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to get the cid value of the url, in this case:

```
"http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=Dee+Zee+8170LB&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14199285063072465458"
```

Can I use regex for this or there is some better way to do it, except the old IndexOf string trimming.

Comment: @Guvante... can you be sure that your edit represents the user's requirements? Changing `&amp;` to `&` is a gamechanger as far as the correct answer goes. I think this needs referring back to the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).

Comment: If we look at the original poster's unedited question, this solution won't work without first de-urlencoding the supplied string. The edit made to the question obscures this.

Comment: +1 ...and as a 1-liner: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&q=Dee+Zee+8170LB&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=14199285063072465458")["cid"]`